# Why is this php code outputted correctly?

Tags: php, global-variables

Yo, I'm studying and relearning some old PHP basics and I got to superglobals

I don't quite understand why this PHP code is as well as why the superglobal doesn't add to be 15 when logically 10 isn't 15, and help or pointers so I can understand this?

```
$y = 10;
$x = 5;

$GLOBALS['y'] = $GLOBALS['x'] + $GLOBALS['y'];
```

I've tried researching this on my own and accepting its because y is just the name of the super global index

none to show other than what's in the question

```
<?php 
$x = 5; 
$y = 10; 

function myTest() { 
    $GLOBALS['y'] = $GLOBALS['x'] + $GLOBALS['y']; 
} 
myTest(); 
echo $y; // outputs 15 
?>
```

the only error here is my brain

When I look at the code I see $GLOBAL['10'] = $GLOBAL['5'] + $GLOBALS['10'];

I don't understand how 15 can equal 10.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Why did you post the same code twice?

Comment: Is this code inside a function?

Comment: In basics forget that any `$GLOBALS` exists. It's way to the hell.

Comment: "the superglobal doesn't add to be 15 when logically 10 isn't 15" what does it add to?

Answer (score 0):

When you refer to a variable outside a function it refers to the global variable. When you refer to a variable inside a function, it normally refers to the local variable, unless the function contains a `global` declaration that makes that variable global.

You can also use the super-global `$GLOBALS`, which always refers to the global variables named in its keys. The [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php) describes it as:

> An associative array containing references to all variables which are currently defined in the global scope of the script. The variable names are the keys of the array.

So when you use `$GLOBALS['y']` it's the same as using the global variable `$y`. Your function is equivalen to:

```
function myTest() { 
    global $x, $y;
    $y = $x + $y;
}
```

Comment: i believe that i got phps logic confused with javascripts' and due to that it confuses me. so in hindsight its because a of $x and $y are global locals and dont apply until the function is ran after echo is called? also for those who dont understand the entire line of code is <?php
$x = 5;
$y = 10;

function myTest() {
    $GLOBALS['y'] = $GLOBALS['x'] + $GLOBALS['y'];
} 

myTest();
echo $y; // outputs 15
?>

Comment: and no the variables are outside of the function which has led to my confusion. I believed that the varaibles would be considered to be a global scope instead of a local

Comment: I understand this gentlemen and its become mind boggling, however when I look at the equation in the function i see this $GLOBAL['10'] = $GLOBAL ['5'] + $GLOBAL['10']; does that explain my confusion a bit better?

Comment: Is it only there as a variable as a variable for algebraic arithmetic?

Comment: The keys of `$GLOBALS` are the names of variables. There's no variable `$10` or `$5`.

Comment: They can be used exactly the same way as any other variables: in arithmetic, string operations, printing, etc. The only thing that's special about `$GLOBALS` is that they're references to the corresponding variables.

Comment: So, just a synopsis, php would read the equation as if it was written in algebraic in plain english and thus knowing where to assign the global variables inside _$GLOABALS_ @Barmar?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question. It's just assigning and adding variables, just like writing `$y = $y + $x;`. The only thing special is that the `$GLOBALS` array is linked to the global variables whose names are the indexes.

Comment: because of the variables vaules it seems that the equation is stating when the `$GLOBALS` is called after the (function is invoked) '10' = '5' + '10';

Comment: It's not an equation, it's a variable assignment.